# MySQL JOIN Rows Issues

Tags: mysql

I'm having some issues with a query that joins two tables. It runs trough the tables far more times than I expect and I can't seem to find why it does this.

My Query is: `SELECT * FROM indexAddress LEFT JOIN indexTx ON indexTx.address_id = indexAddress.id WHERE indexAddress.walletId = '2'`

IndexTx contains rows with transactions and a field with the address ID (address_id)

IndexAddress contains the address data with the ID as primary key.

```
id | select_type | table        | partitions | type       | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | Extra 
1  | SIMPLE      | indexAddress | NULL       | ref        | Wallet ID     | Wallet ID     | 4       | const           | 121  | 100.00
1  | SIMPLE      | indexTx      | NULL       | ref        | Address ID    | Address ID    | 4       | indexAddress.id | 23   | 100.00
```

**My Question is**: Why the table runs indexTx 23 times and not just 1. 121 rows is expected, since it's the number of rows for the expected Wallet ID, but 23 is confusing me.

Comment: Hopefully there is a foreign key relationship. Unique indexes make a difference. Please show us the output of `show create table indexTx \G` and `show create table indexAddress \G`

Answer (score 0):

If one of table has more then one record with walletId == 2 the record will be duplicated.

You need filter more the data or use DISTINCT.

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong since it results in the same thing as running `SELECT * FROM indexTx WHERE indexTx.address_id IN (SELECT id FROM indexAddress WHERE indexAddress.walletId = '2')`

How can I make these two tables join as the walletId would be a record in the first table?

Comment: Without your table structure and this records, is hard understand why the data is duplicated.

Edit your post and put the tables structures and the data of this tables. Or part of data.

Comment: Try SELECT DISTINCT * FROM indexAddress LEFT JOIN indexTx ON indexTx.address_id = indexAddress.id WHERE indexAddress.walletId = '2'

Comment: I will try and see how that works. Since the indexAddress table contains unique records, but more than one record can have the same walletId. I assume the tables would join and that the query would then sort out the valid rows based on indexAddress.walletId as it would if the column was present in the indexTx table natively.

Comment: I think I did try to revert the query with joining indexTx with indexAddress on adress_id = id, and it did the same thing as my original question. I will check in later with some results.

Comment: Please show us the output of `show create table indexTx \G` and `show create table indexAddress \G` – unique constraints make a big difference to the backend query optimizer.